# Trouble Generating html page in php

Tags: php

I have setup a video website but i need help to make $target_file change to the file url but it won't because it is in '' brackets and also at $stringdata

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$myFile = "/home/darlpsou/video.darlingserver.com/$target_file.html"; // or .php   
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w'); // or die("error");  
$stringData = '<h1>Title</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><video tabindex="0" poster="thumb.png" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" controls="controls" width="842" height="417">
 <source src="http://video.darlingserver.com/$target_file" type="video/mp4" />
 <iframe title="YouTube video player" width="842" height="417" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/iYuG55vOIVc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
 </iframe></video></p>';   
 fwrite($fh, $stringData);
 fclose($fh);
```

Comment: use single quote instead  of double or use ignore `(\)`

Comment: Use concatenation then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. One would be to use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
$stringData = sprintf('<h1>Title</h1>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><video tabindex="0" poster="thumb.png" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" controls="controls" width="842" height="417">
     <source src="http://video.darlingserver.com/%s" type="video/mp4" />
     <iframe title="YouTube video player" width="842" height="417" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/iYuG55vOIVc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
 </iframe></video></p>',
   urlencode($target_file)
);
```

Another would be to use HEREDOC syntax:

```
$stringData = <<< HTML
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><video tabindex="0" poster="thumb.png" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" controls="controls" width="842" height="417">
 <source src="http://video.darlingserver.com/$target_file" type="video/mp4" />
 <iframe title="YouTube video player" width="842" height="417" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/iYuG55vOIVc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
 </iframe></video></p>
HTML;
```

Yet another would be to concatenate the variable:

```
$stringData = '<h1>Title</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><video tabindex="0" poster="thumb.png" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" controls="controls" width="842" height="417">
 <source src="http://video.darlingserver.com/' . urlencode($target_file) .'" type="video/mp4" />
 <iframe title="YouTube video player" width="842" height="417" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/iYuG55vOIVc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
 </iframe></video></p>';
```

This is really strings 101 so please refer to http://php.net/strings for additional clues.

Comment: It redirects to s404.html?